# what quantifiers should I use here? Can someone give me an example of some sort

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, quantifiers

I am taking a proof class but I am thoroughly confused, this first qn asks me to use quantifiers but what quantifiers am i supposed to use here? Can someone give me a template of some sort ? thanks[image]

Comment: How would you express the concept in words?  For the first statement, what do you know is always true about the relationship between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$?  How can you express that English statement using quantifiers?

Comment: for all xn where n is an element of the natural numbers, the x(n+1) is larger or equal to xn. what do you think of this? @RobertShore

Comment: $\forall n \in \Bbb N ~(x_{n+1} \geq x_n)$ looks right to me.  For the second statement, try assigning a name to the upper bound, whatever it is.  ($M$ is traditional.)